# Passing function reference to sibling-ish in react + react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a menu which has routes as siblings and in one of those routes, namely *Landing* (see below), I have a function, *scrollToTop*, that I would prefer if the menu has access to. I would strongly prefer to do this with pure reactjs or js but so far I have not been able to do so in a pragmatic way. What approach would you recommend to this problem?

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            scrollToTop: undefined,
        };

        this.landingComp = () => <Landing setScrollToTop={(scrollToTop) => this.setScrollToTop(scrollToTop)} />;
    }

    setScrollToTop(func) {
        this.setState({
            scrollToTop: func,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="content">
                    <Menu scrollToTop={this.state.scrollToTop} />

                    <Route exact path='/' component={this.landingComp} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Landing (component)

```
....
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.setScrollToTop) {
            this.props.setScrollToTop(() => this.scrollToTop());
        }
    }
....
```

Comment: so you want scrollTop() function in Landing component to be accessible in the Menu Component??

Comment: @McRist Yes, indeed! What complicates things for me is the fact that I have to wrap Landing in another component to pass down props because of react-router-dom

Comment: To clarify, my solution is working but react doesn't approve.. "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition...."

Comment: `this.scrollToTop()` is defined in the Landing component ?

Comment: why not define the `scrollToTop()` function in the App component and then pass it to both Landing and Menu component?

Comment: Well, the Landing component has a bunch of scroll-functionality and scrollToTop() is a central part of it, so moving it would basically mean moving all of that functionality to the App component which in turn wouldn't make much sense since App itself has nothing to do with Landing's scroll

Comment: that might seem more organized or something but the best thing to do in react is to always define common functionality in a common ancestor. accessing stuff on children like you have breaks a fundamental pattern

Comment: All right, I'll look into it, many thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The following key-point is the reason for this `Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition`:

- You are using `setState` on unmounted component. These are memory leaks.

Make changes in your code like this:

```
    this.landingComp = () => <Landing setScrollToTop={this.setScrollToTop} />;
```

And

```
    setScrollToTop = func => {
        this.setState({
            scrollToTop: func,
    });
```

But It would be great if you share code via codesandbox so we can resolve the if this doesn't remove the warning. You need to implement isMounted pattern in that component to avoid memory leak. Further organsie your page navigation It could be cumbersome as your app grows faster.
Feel Free to ask any question. And type of warnings shouldn't occur in our App anywhere.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, though I've moved all of the related code into the App component and so the issue is resolved and the function in question is fed down from the parent of the menu and routes to said components as opposed to passing it up and around.